# Examples of makefile that appears to be simple but is complex

Tags: makefile

I am working on a research project involving makefiles. Basically I am trying to construct a language that will explain makefiles in an easy to understand fashion.

Before I can start constructing this language I need to gather examples of makefiles that would be good to illustrate the use of my language. As the title suggests I am looking for makefiles that at first glace might appear to be simple, but after diving deeper into them they are actually confusing, and complex.

An ideal example in this case would be one that makes use of composition; ie using many parts of the makefile to compose the whole. Any examples of this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The "recursive make considered harmful" paper by Miller could provide some insights.

Comment: [Makefile as a functional language program](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/#Makefile-functional) by Oleg Kiselyov

Comment: "explain makefiles in an easy to understand fashion" -- that may be impossible.

Comment: "I am looking for examples of seemingly simple but actually complex and 
confusing Xs" must be off-topic here both as opinion-based and
too broad, so voting to close.